# Meziantou Drag n Drop Blazor: CS1061 'InputFile' does not contain a definition for 'Element'

Tags: drag-and-drop, blazor

I am trying to implement this:
[Meziantou's Blazor Drag n Drop](https://www.meziantou.net/upload-files-with-drag-drop-or-paste-from-clipboard-in-blazor.htm)

However, after copying/pasting the code as shown, I get this compile error:

CS1061  'InputFile' does not contain a definition for 'Element' and no accessible extension method 'Element' accepting a first argument of type 'InputFile' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

What am I missing?

Comment: This is hard to answer as we don't know details of your implementation....

Comment: ElementReference dropZoneElement;
 InputFile inputFile;
 IJSObjectReference _module;
    IJSObjectReference _dropZoneInstance;

    string src;
 protected override async Task OnAfterRenderAsync(bool firstRender)
    {
        if (firstRender)
        {
            // Load the JS file
            _module = await JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import", "./dropZone.js");

            // Initialize the drop zone
            _dropZoneInstance = await _module.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("initializeFileDropZone", dropZoneElement, inputFile.Element);
        }
    }

Answer (score 0):

In .NET 6 there is an Element property on the InputFile component. Prior to .NET 6 it did not exist. The same site that you mention has a [link](https://www.meziantou.net/assets/blazorfileuploaddotnet5.zip?v=27df) at the bottom for source code with a .NET 5 implementation. Basically the same thing, but he uses a container div around the InputFile component, and passes that to the Javascript.